# Why does the letters 'fo' appear at the top of my HTML table when viewing in a web page?

Tags: html

I am learning HTML/CSS currently and have created a table. I opened the page and notice just at the top left above my table are the letters 'fo'. I have triple checked my code and cannot figure out where those letters are coming from.

fo

Table

I checked both my CSS and HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">

            table {
                width: 100%;
            }
            table, th, td{
                border: 1px solid blue;
                padding: 8px;
                text-align: left;
            }
        .tab { text-indent: 40px; }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

      <h1 style=color:darkcyan></h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Topic</th>
                    <th>Background</th>
                    <th>Problem</th>
                    <th>Fix</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Query Result</td>
                    <td>Query Result1</td>
                    <td>Query ResultII</td>
                    <td>Query ResultIII</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example doesn't reproduce the error. Are you sure that's the exact code you're viewing in your browser?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input, I had created a new file and started copying all 100 table rows one by one and I refreshed the page after each copy. I continued my copy and paste troubleshooting and after 30 rows or so, I saw it!  There was 'fo' before one of my <tr> tags which was actually showing at the top of my table. My apologies. You were right, the code I pasted did not include the portion producing the error as it didn't dawn on me that the error would be after 30+ rows of table data and thought the error would be towards the top. Thanks everyone again!

Comment: Tip for the next time: search the source file for `fo`, you would've probably found it faster than copying over little bits of html.